# The global metric can't be generated by coordinate transformation. However, the local metric can always be generated from a locally inertial frame

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, acceleration, equivalence-principle

This is my understanding of the equivalence principal, Is it correct? That is, we can always generate the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ of ANY gravitational field **locally** via the coordinator transformation of the flat Mankowski metric $\eta_{\mu \nu}$. However, the only way to construct the whole metric is via solving Einstein's equations.